# Create a simple button that does not inherit the css properties of Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap.css for styling currently. But I was wondering if I can create a simple `<button>` that does not inherit the css properties of Bootstrap.

Basically I do not want to inherit any properities from Bootstrap for that particular `<button>.`

Comment: You can but you have to overwrite all the properties Bootstrap sets up. How? http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/inheritancecascade

Comment: As far as you don't use any Bootstrap class there is nothing you inherit from it. Did you try to put a simple into your code? `<button>Submit<button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just using it in one place you could create your own button using html/css and add a line of style just before it.

Bootstrap uses 'btn' instead of the standard html , so you can easily create your own.

```
<style> .myButton {background-color:#5edfff; color: #eeeeee; border: 10px solid #0088cc;    border-radius:15px; padding:10px;"}

.myButton:hover {background-color:blue;}
</style>

<button class="myButton">My Personal Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible to remove the Bootstrap styles without removing Bootstrap itself.

You will have to manually unset/reset all the CSS properties to their defaults.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have bootstrap styles means don't add bootstrap `class`

Use your own `class` like this:

CSS:

```
.mystyle{
 background-color:red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="btn" class="mystyle">
            Button
        </button>
```

Or

You can use like this also: (Over writing css)

CSS:

```
 #btn {
            background-color:yellow;
            color:red;
        }
```

or

```
 #btn {
           background-color:yellow !important;
           color:red !important;
         }
```

HTML:

```
<button id="btn" class="btn btn-success">
            Button
        </button>
```

## [LIVE_DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/Pu341CAbmd)